# Filter duplicate object in array

Tags: javascript

This question is asked a lot, but any solution that i've tried didn't work for me.
Maybe used it wrong.

I want to filter duplicated object inside an array i've tried it with `forEach(), find(), filter(), and checking it based on indexOf()` but I coulndt make it work. So I hope someone can help me here with a good explanation how it must be done. I have couple more of the functionality

### MOST RECENT CODE

```js
var list = [{
        name: "Lisa",
        profile: "admin"
    }, {
        name: "Eliza",
        profile: "admin"
    }, {
        name: "Lisa",
        profile: "admin"
    }];

function log(a) {
    console.log(a)
}
var arr = list.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== list
})

log(arr)
```

So this must return

`[{
        name: "Lisa",
        profile: "admin"
    }, {
        name: "Eliza",
        profile: "admin"
    }];`

Because Lisa is a duplicate object.

Comment: How do you define "duplicate"? Having all the same properties with the same values, or just having the same `name`, or...? What is the desired output, an array with no duplicates, or a list of which items *are* duplicates?

Comment: @nnnnnn, the one with the same object, name && profile

Comment: In your example they're not the *same* object, they're two separate objects with the same properties as each other.

Comment: @nnnnnn, ah i see object cant be checked by eqaul to another object. How can I filter it ?

Comment: list.reduce((carry, item, ind) => {
    if (ind == 0 || carry.map(JSON.stringify).indexOf(JSON.stringify(item)) == -1) {
        carry.push(item)
    }
    return carry
}, [])

Comment: @wonyeouuu,this gives me error on node.js

Comment: Maybe it's caused by the arrow function, check this [modified one](https://codepen.io/wonyeouuu/pen/bZxZOW)